# Rails 4. Strange behavior when working with before_validation callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose there are users records in the database. And we decided to add validation in model. Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :name, with: /\A[^\d]*\z/, allow_blank: true

  before_validation :delete_digits_from_name

  def delete_digits_from_name
    self.name = name.gsub!(/\d/, '')
  end
end
```

Scenario 1 in console:

```
User.create(name: 'Username 15')
User.last
=> #<User id: 14154, name: "Username"
```

And it's ok. But there are old record (created before adding validation) and.. scenario 2:

```
user = User.first
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Username 15"
user.save
=> true
user
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Username"
user.reload
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Username 15"
```

But why?? Why changes not saved?

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, but when i do `'Username 15'.gsub(/\d/, '')` i get `"Username "`  (note extra space) not `"Username"`.  Both of these pass your validation regex tho.

Comment: Do you have any other callbacks on User?

Comment: @MaxWilliams About regex - I invented it especially for question, in real app it's ok, doesn't matter. 
No, only this callback.

Comment: When "translating" your actual code into something else for the purposes of the question, there is always the danger that you complicate things by eg accidentally not causing the bug in question.  For example, if i add this validation to my model, then it is saved successfully, ie if i reload it then the  name is `"Username"`.  If you use the code exactly as it is written in your question do you see the same issue?

Comment: @MaxWilliams i'm terribly sorry, i just update question: `gsub!` instead of `gsub`. In my real app i just changed `gsub!` to `gsub` and it resolved my problem. But I dont understand why it doesn't work with `gsub!`

Comment: if it doesn't find a match, `gsub!` will return nil, whereas `gsub` will just return the unchanged string.  I'm not sure if this is the exact problem, i can't see why it would cause it and when i try it in my code it still saves the record.  Either way, you shouldn't set a variable to the result of doing `gsub!` since it changes the object in place anyway.  Either do `self.name = self.name.gsub(/\d/, '')` OR `self.name.gsub!(/\d/, '')` : these two functions are equivalent. (the last one is neater IMO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gsub!` in `delete_digits_from_name` changes the name in place, so Rails thinks `name` is the same thing it loaded from the DB. It's the same object, even though you've changed its value. Rails does this to optimize away DB updates when no data has changed, and in-place editing confuses it.

Switching to `self.name = self.name.gsub(/\d/, '')` (no `!`) assigns a new `String` that Rails will recognize as dirty and needing saving.

You can also add `name_will_change!` after your `gsub!` to tell Rails the attribute needs saving.